# why are my dns changes taking so long to update?

Tags: dns

I have recently started a project where I use Google Cloud as hosting. But I run into a stumbling block. I already had a website hosted in BlueHost and the domain from Godaddy. I hosted the site in google cloud and I did the domain configuration and it works because other people from other places (other cities) tell me they see my new wordpress site with the theme I set for it and the one "hello world" post. However I do not see that, I see my old website with all the bunch of articles we put in it. I was able to log in to the new site late las night but this morning when I visited my website I come to find my OLD WEBSITE. I even tried to look at it in cafe cycbers (places I never go to) and see the same thing my OLD website so this cache problem is not locally in my machine. Has anyone run into this and have figured out how to clear the cache ? Is there anything I can do at the cloud dashboard configuration level? Thanks!

Comment: DNS entries are cached around the world. This is controlled by the TTL settings on each DNS Resource Record. Provided that you have everything set correctly, you will just have to wait. On Windows you can try the command `ipconfig /flushdns` but this only affects your local DNS cache and not your ISP's DNS servers. Typically you have to wait 24 to 72 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per GCP documentation on [Propagation of changes](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/overview#propagation_of_changes), it propagates in two parts:

1. The changes you've made pushed to Cloud DNS's authoritative DNS servers.
2. DNS resolvers picking up the change when their cache of the records expires.

Based on your Time-to-live (TTL) value that you set for your records (assuming N), the DNS resolvers are instructed to cache the records for N hours. You may considering this value shorter value prior to making your change. This help reducing the cache window.